# How to recover data from Aerospike

Tags: aerospike

I have faced a strange issue.

Suddenly Aerospike data has been erased. Provided i have not executed any command to delete the data from the Aerospike.

```
namespace test {
    replication-factor 2
    memory-size 4G
    default-ttl 30d # 30 days, use 0 to never expire/evict.

    storage-engine memory
}
```

I haven’t configured the ttl here but few days back I ran one UDF to set the ttl of all the records to -1 so that it never expires. The sets were being updated periodically, so even then it should not expire after 30 days. I lost all at once which should not be the case.

I am stuck in this since 2 days. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your /etc/aerospike/aerospike.conf configuration file?  Did you set a short TTL on your records and they expired? When did you insert the data (days)?  When did you lose the data (after how many days)?  Did you just write the data once or was it being updated every day or periodically?

Comment: @pgupta please check i have updated my question

Comment: Can you share your UDF code?  When did you insert the data ... about 30 days ago?

Comment: Are there more than one nodes? Were the node[s] restarted? Was all data lost or partial? Short answer to your question is that there isn't a way to recover any of the missing data in this case since the node is not configured to persist data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a [namespace](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/data-model.html#namespaces) that is basically defined to be a cache. It is in-memory with no persistence. For example, a restart of the node will cause the namespace to start empty.

The [Namespace Storage Configuration](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/configure/namespace/storage/index.html) article in the deployment guide gives recipes for storage engine configuration. You can set the [storage](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/storage.html) of a specific namespace to be one of the following:

- Data stored on SSD
- Data stored on a filesystem (not recommended for production)
- Data stored in-memory with persistence to an SSD
- Data stored in-memory with persistence on a filesystem
- Data stored in-memory with no persistence

There is a [special case](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/primary-index.html#single-bin-optimization) of data in-memory for counters, [data-in-index](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/#data-in-index). This is done with persistence.

Comment: The 'data-in-index' parameter currently requires persistence.